# Adding two strings together in the preprocessor

Tags: string, c-preprocessor

I am currently writing a header to make handling my external libs easier.

Here is the minimal code:

```
#pragma once

#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define EXTERNAL_PATH STR(C:/C++ Libraries/)

#define LUA_PATH       EXTERNAL_PATH STR(lua 5.3.4/)
#define LUA_INCLUDE       LUA_PATH       STR(include/)
```

So basically, I include this header and write something like

```
#include LUA_INCLUDE (add this two strings) "lua.hpp"
```

How can I link two strings in the preprocessor together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [`##`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)? And don't stringify (quote) macro params too early because then there is no way back.

Example:

```c
#define MY_QUOTE(a) #a

#define CONCAT_QUOTE(a,b) MY_QUOTE(a##b)

#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b

// this works OK
#include CONCAT(<iostrea, m>)


// this doesn't as iostream should be just in <> rather than "<>"
#include CONCAT_QUOTE(<iostrea, m>)
```